# Removing white shapes from a logo to create vector file

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I made a logo which has a grey stoke which I made in illustrator, but I needed only part of the stroke so I covered the rest using white shapes (rectangles and circles) . How can I remove those white shapes so that I only have the needed stroke and still have a vector file? [image: logo]

Answer (score 1):

... just a general procedure based upon your posted image. I'm assuming the "stroke" is a *brush stroke* and contains some transparency.

This is a *destructive* procedure... meaning it will *permanently* change the artwork. Perform these steps on a **copy** of the art if you want to retain the "build" or "live construction" version.

- Select all
- Choose `Object > Flatten Transparency` and move the slider all the way to the right (vector) and click <kbd>Okay</kbd>
- Click the `Merge` button on the **PathFinder Panel**
- Select *one* of the white objects
- Choose `Select > Same > Fill & Stroke` from the menu
- Hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key

These are merely *basic* steps that *should* work. However, each file is different and may take some extra consideration in some areas. Without direct access to the file itself I can't definitively state these steps will work as expected 100% of the time.